# Pass search parameters (plain text/json) from MVC web client (HttpWebResponse) to Web Api

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, httpwebresponse

Today I'm asking you because I struggle to find a proper solution to this specific problem.

I've got a MVC client application, that communicates via **HttpWebResponse** with a Web Api, designed to retrieve data and operate with the result.

Since all requests were handled within partial views, I call all relevant functions/methods via AJAX.

Like this:

```
$('#dosearch').click(function () {
    var searchstring = "{ ";
    $('#tab_' + $("ul#tabs_searchmask_header li.active").attr('id')).find('input:text').each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.val() !== "") {
            searchstring += "\"" + el.attr('id') + "\": [ \"" + el.val() + "\" ], ";
        }
    });
    searchstring += "}";
    searchstring = searchstring.replace(" ], }", "] }");

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetResults", "SearchResult", null, Request.Url?.Scheme)',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { filecabinet: '@Model.FileCabinet', search: searchstring }
    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#_pviewcontent").html(partialViewResult);
    });
});
```

This creates a simple json-string containing all relevant data I need. Since query size can only hold a maximum of 2000 chars I have to use 'POST' here to extend the amount of data/search parameters that can be passed.

Ultimately this calls the controller, aquiring some additional data an pass it to a wrapper, which communicates with the Web Api controller.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
request.Method = method;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

if (method == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
{
    data = "=" + data;
    var bytes = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(char)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    request.Expect = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I've tried to change the content type to "application/json", but that ended in having a null value as parameter.

This is my Web Api method, that should receive the params and hold them inside **searchparams**.

```
[HttpPost]
public ResultListModel GetResults(string sessionID, string filecabinet, [FromBody]string searchparams)
{
    ....
}
```

All I get is a stringified byte array. I wonder, if there is another approach to just pass the data as they are: plain text (or at least json object).

Any ideas or suggestions?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this riddle by simply changing

```
if (method == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
{
    data = "=" + data;
    var bytes = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(char)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    request.Expect = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

to

```
if (method == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
{
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(JObject.Parse(data));
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ResultListModel GetResults(string sessionID, string filecabinet, [FromBody]string searchparams)
{
    ....
}
```

to

```
[HttpPost]
public ResultListModel GetResults(string sessionID, string filecabinet, [FromBody]JObject searchparams)
{
    ....
}
```

Now my Web Api controller receives an json object that contains all the data that were needed.